# Is there a real world application for the Poincaré Conjecture?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

As the title asks, is there currently a way in which the conjecture, or proof, can be implemented in a real world way?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8993/what-is-the-importance-of-the-poincar%C3%A9-conjecture).

Comment: What is this real world you're taking about? :)